# Aeson and Lens with DeriveGeneric and makeLenses - names don't line up

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

Let's say I have a type `Person`

```
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import Control.Lens

data Person = Person {
    _firstName :: Text,
    _lastName  :: Text,
    _age       :: Int
} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

And I want to automatically derive Lenses and JSON typeclasses for it

```
makeLenses ''Person
instance FromJSON Person
instance ToJSON Person
```

This works correctly, however DeriveGeneric sees my field names as having an underscore and expects my JSON to be formatted accordingly.

```
{ "_firstName": "James" ... etc} -- The underscore doesn't belong here.
```

Obviously I could remove the underscore from the `data` definition itself, but then `makeLenses` wouldn't be able to derive the required getters and setters.

Ideally what I want to be able to do is something like this

```
let person = decode blob
let name = person ^. firstName
```

i.e. I want to be able to derive lenses and JSON instances with all field names lining up correctly with the values in the JSON-REST Api I'm consuming, without having to write much boilerplate.

This seems like such a straight forward thing that I feel I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both `lens` and `aeson` have functions to allow customizable handling of field and constructor names. Since `aeson`'s default is not what you want, and wouldn't work anyway if you want the lens names to be the same as the JSON field names, let's change the `aeson` configuration:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Text hiding (drop)
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Control.Lens

data Person = Person {
    _firstName :: Text,
    _lastName  :: Text,
    _age       :: Int
} deriving (Show, Generic)

makeLenses ''Person

deriveJSON defaultOptions{fieldLabelModifier = drop 1} ''Person

{- alternative Generic version
instance FromJSON Person where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions{fieldLabelModifier = drop 1}
instance ToJSON Person where
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions{fieldLabelModifier = drop 1}
-}
```

For `lens`, the corresponding configurable function would be [`makeLensesWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeLensesWith).